# whiptail or dialog

Tags: bash, shell-script, whiptail, dialog

I am going to create a script which will use user input, so I decided to use `whiptail`.

But now I'm a little bit confused about which one is portable and will work on Ubuntu 10.x and higher and CentOS 5.x and higher.

I know `read`, but I want a tool like `dialog`. If anybody knows any alternative just let me know.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`whiptail` is installed by default on most deb-based systems, while `dialog` is not.

Afair, on rpm-based `whiptail` is also default dialog app.

I guess it matters for you.

So `whiptail` is the right choice from point of portability.

Also `whiptail` is based on `newt`, while `dialog` is based on `ncurses`. From my point of view, the first one is more beautiful (:

Comment: The *script* might be more or less portable, but the dialog program itself is no less portable than whiptail.

Comment: After all written here, why would *whiptail* more beatiful than *dialog*? The latter has more features and better documentation.

Comment: Actually, since whiptail is maintained by debian as a replacement for dialog (which can simply be installed via apt, and I think is installed by default on RedHat & derivatives), I would say that it's the other way around. For portability, choose dialog and make it a dependency on Debian & derived.

Answer (score 14):

According to the [COMPATIBILITY section of the dialog(1) manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/dialog.1.html#compatibility):

> Then there is **whiptail**.  For practical purposes, it is maintained by Debian  (very little work is done by its upstream developers).  Its documentation (README.whiptail) claims
>
> > [whiptail](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/whiptail.1.html)(1) is a lightweight replacement for [dialog](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/dialog.1.html)(1),
> >     to provide dialog boxes for shell scripts.
> >     It is built on the newt windowing library rather than the ncurses library, allowing it to be smaller in embedded environments such as installers,
> >     rescue disks, etc.
> >
> > whiptail is designed to be drop-in compatible with dialog, but has less features: some dialog boxes are not implemented, such as tailbox, timebox, calendarbox, etc.
>
> Comparing  actual  sizes (Debian testing, 2007/1/10): The total of sizes for **whiptail**, the newt, popt and slang libraries is 757 KB.  The  comparable  number  for  **dialog**  (counting ncurses) is 520 KB.  Disregard the first paragraph.
>
> The  second  paragraph is misleading, since  *whiptail** also does not work for common options of **dialog**, such as the gauge box.  **whiptail**  is  less  compatible  with  **dialog**  than  the original mid-1990s dialog 0.4 program.
>
> **whiptail**'s  manpage  borrows  features  from  **dialog**,  e.g.,  but  oddly cites only **dialog** versions up to 0.4 (1994) as a source.  That is, its manpage refers to features which were borrowed from more recent versions of **dialog**, e.g.,
>
> - **--gauge** (from 0.5)
> - **--passwordbox** (from Debian changes in 1999),
> - **--default-item** (from **dialog** 2000/02/22),
> - **--output-fd** (from **dialog** 2002/08/14).
>
> Somewhat  humorously,  one may note that the **popt** feature (undocumented in its manpage) of using a "--" as an escape was documented in **dialog**'s manpage about a year  before  it  was mentioned in **whiptail**'s manpage.  **whiptail**'s manpage incorrectly attributes that to **getopt** (and is inaccurate anyway).

Answer (score 10):

(This is not necessarily an answer, but I posted as such due to the amount of code. I have no practical experience with `whiptail`. Will delete this later if a `whiptail` user posts a tested solution on this.)

As [Bash Shell Scripting/Whiptail](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail) writes:

> From its README: whiptail is designed to be drop-in compatible with
>   dialog(1), but has less features: some dialog boxes are not
>   implemented, such as tailbox, timebox, calendarbox, etc.

That means you not necessarily have to decide for one or the other. Just detect which one is available then let the script use it:

```
# check whether whiptail or dialog is installed
# (choosing the first command found)
read dialog <<< "$(which whiptail dialog 2> /dev/null)"

# exit if none found
[[ "$dialog" ]] || {
  echo 'neither whiptail nor dialog found' >&2
  exit 1
}

# just use whichever was found
"$dialog" --msgbox "Message displayed with $dialog" 0 0
```

(Yes, the above detection will fail on tools installed inside directories with name containing newline characters. I just kept it simple.)

Comment: Bruh... `timebox` and `calendarbox` were major to me... Used `dialog` instead. Who the heck won't implement these for any dialog software!? IMHO The main problem in these both is a bad/weak color customization. `8 colors`? Oh dear...

Answer (score 9):

Why not use both:

(Requires bash 4)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
t(){ type "$1"&>/dev/null;}
function Menu.Show {
   local DIA DIA_ESC; while :; do
      t whiptail && DIA=whiptail && break
      t dialog && DIA=dialog && DIA_ESC=-- && break
      exec date +s"No dialog program found"
   done; declare -A o="$1"; shift
   $DIA --backtitle "${o[backtitle]}" --title "${o[title]}" \
      --menu "${o[question]}" 0 0 0 $DIA_ESC "$@"; }



Menu.Show '([backtitle]="Backtitle"
            [title]="Title"
            [question]="Please choose:")'          \
                                                   \
            "Option A"  "Stuff...."                \
            "Option B"  "Stuff...."                \
            "Option C"  "Stuff...."
```

Comment: So complicated.  Why not something like this: `which whiptail && window=whiptail; which dialog && window=dialog; [ -z window ] && echo "no whiptail or dialog"`.  Then the op can just do ` $window --title foo --msgbox bar 87 5 `.

Comment: because globals are bad, and functions are good?

Comment: Okay, fair enough.