# How to create a GUI in shell script without any third party libs just like setup command

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, gui

How to create a GUI in shell script without any third party libs (like setup command)

Comment: The question is too broad. What do you mean by "third party libs"? You're going to need a GUI lib to create a GUI. Whether it's included or not on your machine depends on too many factors.

Comment: @rahmu I need to create script Using only basic default packages installed on any linux machine and show a GUI like setup command ..

Comment: There's no such thing as "basic default packages installed on any linux machine". You cannot make any assumption about what's on a user's machine beyond a linux kernel. We could help you more if you told us which systems you're targeting specifically.

Comment: There's also no generic "setup command" that would give us any indication of what you are after. Perhaps you can provide a screenshot or even just a mockup showing what exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `whiptail` or `dialog`

Have look at this thread:

[Whiptail or dialog](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64627/whiptail-or-dialog)

[Bash Shell Scripting/Whiptail](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail)

Comment: Is whiptail is available in RHEL 6 by default ???